# Server Hardware for Wordpress

Tags: performance

Is this hardware good for 5000/7000 daily user?

*Amazon EC2 instance*

```
         | vCPU | Mem (GiB) | Storage SSD (GB)
---------------------------------------------
r3.large | 2    | 15,25     | 3 x 40
```

3 SSD Storage are used for:

1. Ubuntu SO
2. Wordpress
3. MySQL 5.6

Server service are:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.6 (PHP-FPM) with OpCache
- Memcache
- MySQL 5.6

Wordpress use:

- W3 Total Cache
- SEO Yoast
- AVADA theme

The question is: I'm scared! 2 CPU it seem few... are really few?

Comment: This is offtopic for wordpress developent.  Maybe ask this over in Server Fault? http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @HowardE I know... but is really specific for wordpress... All wordpress guys are here...

Comment: There is no easy/reasonable answer to expect. And still off-topic as mentioned by @HowardE. There are [server stress test tools](http://bfy.tw/6U7G) which can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why AWS is great.  Monitor you server and if that's either too much or not enough, scale up or down.  But it sounds like more than enough.

Comment: And this @Howard is the reason why ppl keep asking off-topic questions. They know that they still get an answer. (*and yes I know/understand why some still answer but what are rules for if ppl think there is no reason to  follow those*.)